# I tried toggling the alarm button to checked button for the targeted task but is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, use-state, reduce

I tried toggling the alarm button to check button for the targeted task but the alarm icon of all the tasks change too. Am using the redux toolkit

This is my state

```
const initialState = {
  isHideForm: false,
  taskDesc: "",
  date: "",
  time: "",
  user: "",
  taskTitle: "",
  isEditing: false,
  editID: null,
  isCompleted: false,
  data: [],
};
```

Here is the reducer for toggling the button

```
 completed(state, action) {
      let item = state.data.find((x) => x.id === action.payload);
      if (item) {
        state.isCompleted = !state.isCompleted;
      }
    },
```

This is the on-click button

```
<button onClick={(e) => handleCompleted(e, d.id)}
                className="border-y-2 border-r-2 border-gray-200 p-2 rounded-r">
                {isCompleted ? <GrCheckmark /> : <FaBell />}
              </button>
```

Comment: You can't modify objects in react and expect components to rerender. You babe to create a new object.

Comment: So how can I go about it?

Comment: Take notice how state is created in each case and returned https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer

Answer (score 0):

You've to return a new state object

```
if(item) { 
return {...state, isCompleted: !state.isCompleted }
}
```